# Web API 2 RequestContext.Principal returning previous username with Windows Authentication

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I have an API built with Web API 2 (VB.Net), running on IIS 7.5 that relies on Windows Authentication and is queried by an AngularJS app.  Everything has worked fine for a year or so but we now have a user that we've changed their username a couple of days ago as they have recently got married.

All normal Windows login processes work with the new username however the credentials that the API tries to use always refers to the old username.

**AngularJS:**

```
$http.get($rootScope.urlAPI + 'access/', {      
  cache: false,
  withCredentials: true
}).success 
...
```

**Web API 2:**

```
<HttpGet>
<Route("api/access")>
<ResponseType(GetType(UserAccessDTO))>
<NoCachePolicy>
<Authorize> _
Function GetStaffAccessForApp() As UserAccessDTO
  Dim objUser As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = RequestContext.Principal
  Dim strUsername As String = objUser.Identity.Name
  ' strUsername is somehow returning their old username
...
```

***strUsername is somehow returning their old username***

Directly querying the API from the browser returns the same JSON result with the old username so I don't believe the issue is specifically with the AngularJS app but somewhere between the browser and the API...

This issue occurs from both IE11 and Google Chrome and I've tried clearing the browser cache, deleted cookies and also tried restarting the API's web-site service in IIS to reload the API.

We only have 2 domain controllers and it's been a couple of days so they are definitely synced and I've scrolled through the attributes of her account but can find no reference to her old username there so I'm at a loss as to where this is coming from :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with similar issue, it seems to have resolved only after a reboot of the servers.  We conducted regular monthly maintenance which involves progressive restart of all servers.  Somewhere between rebooting domain controllers, database server and API server it has resolved the issue for the user this morning.

A bit disappointing we couldn't nail down exactly where it was... but probably cached somewhere.